# How to get IIS7 Manager in English?

Tags: iis-7

is it possible to switch to english in IIS 7 when working in a foreign country ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It depends on the language of current operating system. But you can try to uninstall IIS and reinstall using with English version of current operating system cd or dvd. Anyway i didn't try that but it might work.